# Login status in React

Tags: reactjs

I created authorization in javascript. Then if success login I redirect to React project with url parameter `http://localhost:3000/?phoneNum=%2B77072050399`

Then in React I get `userId` by using the passed url parameter => `phoneNumber` using axios.

I realized it in `App.js`. Code below:

```
let url = window.location.href;
    let params = (new URL(url)).searchParams;
    const userPhoneNum = encodeURIComponent(params.get('phoneNum'));

    const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState(null);
    const getUserToken = async() => {
        try {
            const data = await axios
                .get(`https://stormy-escarpment-89406.herokuapp.com/users/getToken?phone_number=${userPhoneNum}`)
                .then(response => {
                    setUserToken(response.data);
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log('No such user! Error in getting token!');
                });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getUserToken();
        console.log(userToken);
    }, userToken);
```

So, when I go to next page `localhost:3000/places`, it is requesting for userToken again with parameter `null`, because there is no param `phoneNum`.

How to make it to request **only one time** and **save the userId** after it is taken in main page. So, then only when I click LogOut button reset the variable where userID is saved.

Comment: use local storage in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that without using any third party libraries you can use browser's in built storage api

So, when you receive the token, you can store that in the local storage of the browser using localstorage.setItem and later when you wan to see if the token is there or not just read from there using localStorage.getItem

```
 const getUserToken = async() => {
            try {
                const data = await axios
                    .get(`https://stormy-escarpment-89406.herokuapp.com/users/getToken?phone_number=${userPhoneNum}`)
                    .then(response => {
                        setUserToken(response.data);
                        Storage.setItem('token',JSON.stringify(response.data))
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log('No such user! Error in getting token!');
                    });
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
```

For Logout you can simply remove the token using localStorage.removeItem

Comment: says: localstorage is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by using the react-cookie library

```
npm i react-cookie
```

Can be easily implemented in your code by

```
cookies.set('key', value, { path: '/' });
cookies.get('key')
```

After getting the userNumber form the param

const userPhoneNum = encodeURIComponent(params.get('phoneNum'));
 cookies.set('userphoneNum', userPhoneNum);

View the documentation for more information

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie